# Django and multi-stage servers

Tags: django, deployment

I am working with a client that demands multi-stage server setup: development server, stage server and production/live server.

Stage should be as stable as it can be to test all those new features we develop at the development server and take this to the live server in the end.

We use git and github for version controlling. I use Ubuntu server edition as the OS.

The problem is, I have never working in such multi-stage server plan. What software/projects would you recommend to do a proper way of handling such setup, especially deployment and moving a new feature developed to the stage and then to the live server ?

Comment: For those that voted to close, how are tools and processes regarding deployment not related to software development?

Comment: I'm also curious to hear that, deployment and related tools are an essential part of the software life-cycle.

Comment: Josh: unfortunately this question have no single good answer (is to open). This is why people are voting to close it. This kind of question would be better for some kind of forum, but not for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Tomas not all questions **need** to have a single good answer. I provided two answers with pros and cons. This question is perfectly answerable. Provide a set of tools with advantages and disadvantages of each, and let the OP (and future visitors) investigate further and decide for themselves. The kind of 'open' questions the faq refers to are things like "what programming language is the best?" ie. questions that lead to discussions. There is no discussion to be had here.

Comment: Make sure your web host is using virtualisation and that you can easily clone servers. This makes clones your production server (to create a staging server) very easy. I use Linode and it's great.

Comment: tried to vote for close but blocked because of the bounty. This should be on webmasters, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7):

We use two different methods of moving code from environment to environment. The first is to use branches and triggers with our source control system (mercurial in our case, though you can do the same thing with git). The other, is to use fabric, a python library for executing shell code across a number of servers.

Using source control, you can have several main branches, like `production` `development` `staging`. Say you want to move a new feature into staging. I'll explain in terms of mercurial, but you can port the commands over to git and it should be fine.

```
hg update staging
hg merge my-new-feature
hg commit -m 'my-new-feature > staging'
hg push
```

You then have your remote source control server push to all of your web servers using a trigger. A trigger on each web server will then do an update and reload the web server.

To move from staging to production, it's just as easy.

```
hg update production
hg merge staging
hg commit -m 'staging > production'
hg push
```

It's not the nicest method of deployment, and it makes rolling back quite hard. But it's quick and easy to set up, and still a lot better than manually deploying each change to each server.

I won't go through fabric, as it can get quite involved. You should read [their documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/index.html) so you understand what it is capable of. There are plenty of tutorials around for fabric and django. I highly recommend the fabric route as it gives you lots more control, and only involves writing some python.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [nice branching model for git](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (as it is also used by github itself for example). You can easily apply this branching model using [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow), which is a git extension that enables you to apply some high level repository operations that fit into this model. There's also a [nice blogpost](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html) about this.

I do not know what exactly you want to automize in your deployment workflow, but if you apply the model mentioned above, most of the correct version handling is done by git.

To add some further automatic processing to this, [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/index.html) is a simple but great tool, and you will find [many tutorials about its usage](http://lethain.com/deploying-django-with-fabric/) (also in combination with git).

For handling python dependencies using [virtualenv and pip](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/) is for sure a very good way to go.

If you need something more complex,eg. to handle more than one django instance on one machine and for handling system wide dependencies etc checkout [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or [chef](http://protecinnovations.co.uk/blog/2011/05/automated-deployment-with-git-and-chef/).

Answer (score 2):

Try Gondor.io or Ep.io, they both make it pretty easy (gondor especially excels in this area) to have two+ instances with very similar code, from your VCS -- and to move data back and forth. (if you need an invite, ask either in IRC, but if I recall, they're both open now)